# How to maximize performance in React when taking controlled input from multiple components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks, web-frontend

I have created a Parent component that has multiple child components. Each of these child components have data that is passed down to the parent component which will send off that data to an api call. The structure looks like this

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [child1input, setChild1Input] = useState("");
  const [child2input, setChild2Input] = useState("");
  const [child3input, setChild3Input] = useState("");
  const [child4input, setChild4Input] = useState("");

  const submitData = async () => {
    const payload = {
      input1: child1input,
      input2: child2input,
      input3: child3input,
      input4: child4input
    };

    await axios.post('route', {...payload});
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Child1 input={child1input} setInput={setChild1Input} />
      <Child2 input={child2input} setInput={setChild2Input} />
      <Child3 input={child3input} setInput={setChild3Input} />
      <Child4 input={child4input} setInput={setChild4Input} />
      <Button onClick={submitData}>Submit</Button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Now clearly every time each component updates the parent's state (every keystroke for input boxes) it updates the parent component and therefor every child component as well. This has a HUGE performance impact and causes the input text box behavior to be super laggy.

I would like to know, how would I handle input change from one textbox in some child component without causing a re-render of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.memo` for `Child` component and `useCallback` for `Parent` one

```
const handleInput1 = useCallback(
    (e) => {
        setChild1Input(e.target.value)
    },[setChild1Input],
)
<Child1 input={child1input} setInput={handleInput1} />

------------------------------------------------------

export default React.memo(Child1);
```

Comment: This still causes every component to re-render.

Comment: do you use `React.memo` for all your `Child`? Can you send codesandbox?

Comment: In the process of creating a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-h7cdw I realized what you suggested actually works. So thank you. However, it shouldn't matter if the main component gets re-rendered right? Since the child components are now memoized?

Comment: yes, the main component gets re-rendered is not a problem, because your state has been set in your main component, so you can not avoid that when your state change

Comment: I did notice though based on the sandbox I linked, textbox values aren't updating.

Comment: the problem is your child component, the `WrappedChild1` is nunnecessary

Comment: Is it possible with the WrappedChild1? In the real code it gets quite big so I have separated all the child components and wrapped them.

Comment: i fix your code, please check https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-heyrovsky-bfebg

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I just realized with what you provided I can essentially create regular components and wrap them with a memoized one at the end.

Thank you once again.